# Why is my array length equal to 0?

Tags: javascript, html

Why do I output an array length of 0? It's making my loop not work and my understanding of this code not clear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <title>My Awsome Website</title>



</head>

<body>

    <h1>My list</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
        </ul>

    <script>

        var list = document.getElementsByTagName('<li>');
        document.write(list.length);


        /*
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            list[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            list[i].style.color = 'white';
        }
        */

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

There are no elements with tag name `<li>`.

There are several with tag name `li`, though.

The line should be:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
```

use above. That `getElementsByTagName` has only one param which is the tag name of the required element.